# MSBuild build removes resources when building multiple solutions

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

We have a project with multiple solutions which some of them contain resources (images, javascript, html). The issue is that when building all solutions in order, the latest solution with resources removes resources from other projects that were allready build.

How to setup the solution to not remove "old" Resources?

Comment: Not very clear your question. What do you mean "We have a project with multiple solutions"? Do you mean "We have a solution with multiple projects" or "You have a folder which include many solutions"? And as suggestion, you`d better provide your project structure here and some steps so that we could reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes, there is a folder with multiple .sln files and a script that builds them all in order into a BUILD folder. But when compiling, newer solutions remove Resources from other solutions.

Comment: Have you set the output path to one folder "BUILD" for all solutions? If yes, the latest solution with resources removes previous resources, you can set different output path for different solution by property: `msbuild mysolution1.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\Build\Solution1`in your scripts. Or if you do not mind, you can share your scripts, I will check it.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the issue. We'll discuss the solution you provided. But ultimately we would like to have all resources in one place. The current fux is to have all resources in the last solution. But then there is a problem not knowing which resources belong where. Can you disable the compiler from removing old resources (only replace existing ones if they exist)?

Comment: If have all resources in one place is your ultimate goal, you can create a custom task in the project of latest solution to copy all resources to the single folder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx BTW, have you add `/t:Clean` or `/t:Rebuild` in the build command line in your scripts? If yes, those properties will clean the output folder before build.

Answer (score 0):

> How to setup the solution to not remove "old" Resources?

Since we do not have your build script, it is hard for us to make sure the directly solution for this issue, but I could provide you some possibilities for this issue so that you could troubleshoot this issue by yourself.

According to your question and comments, you have a script that builds all solution in order into a **BUILD** folder, this may be the reason for your issue.

When you set the output path to one folder "BUILD" for all solutions, the latest solution with resources removes previous resources. You can set different output paths for different solutions by property in your script:

`msbuild mysolution1.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\Build\Solution1in`

If you still want those build results in to one folder, you can add a build event or custom [Copy Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to copy all results into one folder.

BTW, if you add any `/t:Clean` or `/t:Rebuild` in the build command line in your script, please remove it. Because those properties will clean the output folder before build.

Hope this helps.